# Text in Sketch App: Character spacing to code

Tags: sketch-app

I'm using Sketch app 46.2 and am creating a UI mockup where I'm changing the character spacing of some text to 0.2 (the default is 0) but I don't know how to communicate this to developers.

How do I translate this into an HTML/CSS specification that they'll understand? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The CSS property this relates to is `letter-spacing`.

It doesn't display it within Sketch's interface, but the value is in pixels. So for your example of `0.2`, that would translate to `letter-spacing: .2px;`

---

[image]

If you right click on any object within Sketch, you can `Copy CSS Attributes` and it'll grab as many attributes and values that particular object may have.

So in the context of a Text layer, this is the raw output:

`/* Roundup of the lates: */
font-family: Lato-Light;
font-size: 16px;
color: #FFFFFF;
letter-spacing: -0.1px;
text-align: center;`

---

Lastly, here's documentation of the spec:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing

And what the value actually does (emphasis mine):

> Specifies extra inter-character space **in addition** to the default space between characters. Values may be negative, but there may be implementation-specific limits. User agents may not further increase or decrease the inter-character space in order to justify text.

Comment: No problem @duralexglass  If you could mark my answer as correct, it'll help out others!

Comment: I tried to up vote it but I can't because my reputation  is <15. I can't see a "mark as correct" option...

Comment: @duralexglass — Ah, it's all good then :)